# Dynamic HTML Causing Issue for Determining which Button was Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this block of code:

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            print"<span>";
                print"<input type='button' value='+' />";
                print"<input type='button' value='-' />";
                print"<span>counter_value</span>";
            print"</span>";
            print"<br />";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The idea is that you click on one of the buttons and the value in the inner `<span>` tag increments or decrements by 1. The HTML/PHP itself displays the above perfectly well and displays the elements. However, my issue is that `$array` can have an arbitrary number of elements. If there are (for example) five outer `<span>` tags, I want to know which one of the buttons has been clicked .(This would be done using jQuery) Because the HTML is generated in a for-loop I'm reluctant to give the elements IDs.

In the jQuery I think I will need something like this:

```
var div = $('#mydiv');

    div.on("click", "a", function(){
    //Determine the <span> tag where the button was clicked.
    //Get the counter value from the inner <span> tag within this <span> tag.
    //Determine which button was clicked.
    //Add/subtract one from value and update value in inner <span> tag.
    });
```

I hope I've made the issue clear enough to be understandable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Give the buttons a class...

Comment: jQuery invokes event handlers with `this` bound to the element involved.

Comment: OK I can give them a class and I know how to use jQuery's $(this) keyword. My question is though, is there a property within $(this) that enables me to determine which button was clicked?

Comment: This isn't dynamic HTML. You're creating all the elements in PHP on the server, not adding them in Javascript on the client.

Comment: did you try to do the JS that you outlined in that function?

Comment: `this` _is_ the button that was clicked, you don't need a property. You can find the span using DOM traversal functions.

Comment: or use $(this).val() to check if it's + or -

Comment: @Barmar I tried using jQuery's `parent()` method to get the parent but all that appears is everything inside the button's parent.

Comment: You don't want the parent, you want the span that's a sibling of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just given the button elements class names to determine whether to add or subtract

```
<?php
$array = array_fill(0,2,'Hello World');
?>

<div id='mydiv'>
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            print"<span>";
                print"<input type='button' value='+' class='plus' />";
                print"<input type='button' value='-' class='minus' />";
                print"<span class='counter_value'>0</span>";
            print"</span>";
            print"<br />";
        }
    ?>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mydiv').on('click','input[type="button"]',function(){
    var el = $(this).parent('span').find('.counter_value');
    if($(this).hasClass('plus')){
        $(el).html(parseInt($(el).text()) + 1);
    }else{
        $(el).html(parseInt($(el).text()) - 1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I click both + and - the value in `.counter_value` subtracts.

Comment: did you add class names to the button inputs?

Comment: Yes and it matches what I have in the if-statement.

Comment: strange as i tested this before i posted.

Comment: Apologies but I made a mistake when testing it. When using the `hasClass()` method I passed in the class name with the '.' which was causing the if-statement to fail. The example now works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mydiv :button").click(function() {
    var span = $(this).siblings("span");
    var direction = $(this).val() == '+' ? +1 : -1;
    span.text(function(i, oldval) {
        return parseInt(oldval, 10) + direction;
    });
});
```